# Are '$a$ divides $b$' and '$b$ is divided by $a$' different?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The textbook says:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be integers with $a \neq 0$. We say that $a$ divides $b$ (or that $a$ is a divisor of $b$, or that $a$ is a factor of $b$) if $b=ac$ for some integer $c$.

But the textbook also says:

> Suppose that when $b$ is divided by $a$, the quotient is $q$ and the remainder is $r$.

I'm confused because I think in terms of English, '$a$ divides $b$' has the same meaning as '$b$ is divided by $a$'. For example, 'I kicked a ball' is equivalent as 'A ball was kicked by me.' However it seems that those two sentences are not identical since $a$ divides $b$ does not allow the remainder.

Comment: "$b$ Is divided by $a$" is not saying that $a$ is a divisor of $b$.  It is saying that $a$ and $b$ have an unknown relationship as far as divisibility goes, and $q$ and $r$ are the defining characteristics of that relationship.

Comment: The equivalent of $\,a$ divides $b\,$ is $\,b$ is divisible by $a\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of "divides $b$" as a property a number can have, like "is even". (For example, "divides $10$" is a property $2$ has but $7$ doesn't, just like "is even" is a property $2$ has but $7$ doesn't.)

Think of "$b$ divided by $a$" as a function taking $a$ and $b$, and returning a quotient/remainder pair.

---

Strictly, one might say "thing DIVIDES thing" is a function from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\{\mathrm{True}, \mathrm{False}\}$. "thing DIVIDED BY thing" is a function $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about positive integers, I would say

- $a$ divides $b$
- $b$ is divisible by $a$
- $b$ divided by $a$ leaves a remainder of $0$
- $a$ is a factor of $b$
- $a$ is a divisor of $b$
- $b$ is a multiple of $a$

were equivalent statements.  In the second expression, I used *divisible* rather than your *divided*